# SE Account mismatch

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

This user: https://security.stackexchange.com/users/37636/jamal

seems to be this one:

http://stackexchange.com/users/2207373/jamal?tab=reputation

But the network account tabs don't show the security.SE account and I'd really like to personally reach out to him – there is something wrong with his account.

I checked, and on the security.SE join date (Jan' 21, 2014), the "Code Review" Jamal SE network account [did *not* get](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=21) 100 points of association bonus, while the "Security" Jamal did – that's really strange, unless it's a bug, or a feature I didn't know, or someone's impersonating him.

So. **Can someone at least check with the "Code Review" Jamal that the "Security" Jamal is him? Or is there some other way to figure this out?**

"Security" Jamal's profile doesn't even have a link to a SE network page (which, again, might point to a bug considering his 100 point association bonus).

Comment: Yes, that is my account and the accepted answer is correct.  In most cases something like this is due to hidden accounts, and one way you can make sure is by looking for similar activity and/or quality of posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of that is a function called a "[Hidden Account"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268158/what-is-a-hidden-account) - where you can set up one or more of your Stack Exchange accounts to be visible only to you and to moderators.

This is why when I carried out a quick check I could see his Security account, but you couldn't.

If you (or a moderator) look at your list where a hidden account exists, it will look like this:

[image]

Example taken from [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276597/this-account-is-hidden-and-will-is-only-shown-to-you-and-moderators).